# Notify if outbound message user has not proper rights

Tags: campaign, workflowoutboundmessage

We send an outbound message if "something" changes on the campaign object via user interaction.
If the outbound message user has not the "send outbound message" right, the user interacting with the campaign will not recognize that.
Is it possible to show some notification (like a pop-up) if the outbound message user has not the proper rights? (I know I can send an email but that is not what I want to do)
What would be the best way to detect if the outbound message user has proper rights?
Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose behind restricting outbound messages for a certain user? I believe you might not understand what this feature's purpose is.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox there is no restricting for a certain user. The right to send outbound messages can be set on profile level. Furthermore, I am talking about misconfiguration of our integration and I would like to show some "hints" for that.

Comment: My point is that this is basic profile management. Only administrators can configure this permission, so it's always an intentional act. There's no point in notifying a random user if outbound messaging was disabled for them, because they can't do anything about it. Administrators should take care to set profile permissions correctly.

Comment: Yes good point! But sometimes mistakes happen. And I guess it's always good practice to show a meaningful "error" message. But thank you very mutch for your assessment!